# How to programmatically determine a network card is a virtual one?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, virtual-machine

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/NetworkCards/, I can enumerate each network card installed on my machine. However, some application, especially virtual machines, will install some virtual network cards.

My question is: How to programmatically determine a network card is a virtual one?

Comment: Check out the article at: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/11/04/find-only-physical-network-adapters-with-wmi-win32_networkadapter-class.aspx and fiddle with the logic to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the virtual machine. If it uses for example QEMU as the hardware emulation it will be very hard to determine that it's not "the real thing" - at best, you may notice that it's faster than a the real thing should be, but you'd be hard pushed to know that.

Of course, a virtual machine may also have real network cards installed into the virtual machine. So you can't really know for sure that it is or isn't a real one, even if you, somehow, know that you are running on a virtual machine.

If it's a "paravirtual" network adapter, then you may find that the manufacturer is something like Citrix, VMWare or Oracle, or something like that.

I'm not entirely sure there is a good reason to know the difference...